# WPF Default Style for All Window

Tags: c#, wpf, styles

I am new to WPF and am trying to use Mahapps.MetroWindow to style up my multi-windows application.

The Problem is that I cannot set a default style for all windows as shown.

```
    <Style TargetType="Controls:MetroWindow" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Controls:MetroWindow}}">
            <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource icon}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="GlowBrush" Value="Black" />
        </Style>
```

Can someone give me a pointer on how to achieve this, Thanks

Comment: put your style in App.xaml,it will apply to all windows

Comment: I did put it in app.xaml

Comment: So the style is not applied ?

Comment: [link] https://imgur.com/a/bh78E

Snoop shows no icon are set, and the 2nd pic shows my app.xaml

Comment: I just found out that MetroWindow Style is in Generic.xaml, is this mean I cannot implement my style?

Comment: [Dbl's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29124602/adding-custom-styles-to-mahapps-metro-existing-ones) reply using code behind is your answer.